# JQuery Reading JSON (global/local variable)

Tags: jquery, json, global-variables

So I'm trying to assign data from JSON to a global variable to use it multiple times later, but I get this problem. First alert passes ok, but for the second one I get cannot read propery 4 of undefined.

```
  var refference=[]
  $.getJSON('letters.json', function(data) {
              refference=data.letters
              alert(refference[1][4])
        })
  alert(refference[1][4])
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Ajax is asynchronous, the alert on the outside will happen long before the ajax completes. http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/key-concepts/ *"A is for Asynchronous"*

Answer (score 5):

The second `alert(refference[1][4])` will give you an error because at that point in time, the `$.getJSON()` request has not returned yet. So `refference` object is still `[]`, therefore property 4 is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin B said, the alert is firing before the ajax call is complete. You'd have to put the second alert (or any other function) in the success callback of the ajax request to ensure that it fires after the data is completely loaded.

something like:

```
$.getJSON('letters.json', function(data) {
              refference=data.letters;
              alert(refference[1][4]);
        }).success(function(){
                    alert(refference[1][4]);
                  });
```

[Here's a working jsFiddle example using a JSON webservice](http://jsfiddle.net/b7ALS/44/)

Comment: note, your .done() part is invalid and will still alert undefined or throw an error

Comment: yeah, my bad. Should have used '`success`. Will update my answer and included a working jsFiddle

Comment: No, success is depreciated. .done() was correct, but .done(alert(...)) is wrong, so is .success({...})

Comment: Are you sure that "success" is depreciated for `getJSON`? because according to the jquery API it's not. success({...}) also works fine in the example I posted. (or at least it did until the web service's API's demo limit was exceeded)

Comment: I see what you're saying about `success({...})` I fixed that in my fiddle (added function() )but hadn't pasted that into the answer above.

Comment: So 

.success(function(){
       alert(refference[1][4]);
             });

Should work fine? Thanks a lot!!